# ES6 static final property of class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**How can I assign a static property (constant) to my ES6 class?**

Pseudo code about what I want to achieve:

```
class MyClass {

    static run() {
        // do something
    }

    static CONSTANT = {
        foo: "bar"
    }
}

MyClass.run(); // this works
console.log(MyClass.CONSTANT); // this sadly not
```

Which gives me the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

Comment: [`The static keyword defines a static method for a class.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)

Comment: How about using `Object.defineProperty(MyClass, "CONSTANT", {value: {foo:"bar"}})`

Answer (score 0):

The class syntax only allows method definitions. But you can assign the property outside:

```js
class MyClass {}
MyClass.CONSTANT = {
  foo: "bar"
};
console.log(MyClass.CONSTANT); // this works
```

Comment: This is not a constant. It's reassignable.

Comment: @TedBarth Well, just define it as non-enumerable non-writable. There is no such a thing as a constant property, only constant bindings. And it seems you are confused by the difference between static and constant.